Разделение команд в телеграмм-боте
Через botfather были настроены команды, все работает. Но эти команды видят все пользователи, а нужно что бы видел только 1(допустим по id). В идеале, что бы для админа были видны все команды, а для обычных пользователей либо свои отдельные, либо никакие. Это возможно?

Честно говоря, тоже когда-то задался этим вопросом, но не нашёл решения, чтобы в списке команд не было для каких-то пользователей команд, а для других были. Сделал решение другим образом: добавил в базу данных необходимых пользователей по id телеграма и, когда они используют ту или иную команду, идёт проверка на доступ к ней. Так что видимость становится малозначимой так, как использовать могут всё равно только доверенные.

Ну да, это тоже у меня реализовано. Ну ладно тогда, спасибо!
